# What does scream mean in these sentenses?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I just found an interesting usage of scream which I couldn't locate its meaning in dictionaries. Two examples are as follows:

> When the speaker (who is a journalist) wore a wrinkly blouse, she said:
> This doesn't scream real deal news reporter. This screams sad, frumpy lady
> with no mirrors in her house.

> When the speaker wanted to introduce a very cute picture:
> If this doesn’t scream cute I don’t know what does.

I couldn't locate the meaning of it in dictionaries. Are the two scream in the two sentences the same? Do they mean "represent" here?

Comment: It's a common enough usage of the word "scream" that I'm surprised it isn't in dictionaries. I just checked the Oxford, and it's not there. Quite odd

Comment: It's an ***emphatic*** version of things like [*The way you dress **says** a lot about you.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dress+says+a+lot+about+you%22)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are slang based on a metaphor. The meaning is “imply with such force that the implied conclusion should be immediately apparent.”

The metaphor is between implied meaning and explicit speech. A subtle implication becomes a “whisper,” and an obvious implication becomes a “shout.”

Comment: Yep. In Frank's first example, the journalist would like to wear clothes that strongly and clearly give the clear impression she's a serious journalist, but the shirt she had instead made it clear she wasn't special. In the second, the picture is so cute it's unmistakable.